# Write windbg command output to file, but not console

Tags: windows, windbg

In windbg, I'm looking for a mechanism to take the output of a command (specifically, a command inside of a breakpoint) and have it appended to a file, and *not* written to a console.

Currently I setup the process with `.logappend C:\path\to\log` and then enable a few breakpoints with:

```
bp WIN32U!{function} ".echo '===WIN32K-START==='; k; .echo '===WIN32K-END==='; g"
```

This works great, except the volume of output written to the console causes serious performance issues. I'm hopeful there's a way to get the same output to my log file, without the overhead of writing to the windbg console.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? A clear problem statement goes a long way. And it helps future visitors, too.

Comment: @IInspectable my question is if there's a way to write command output to a file, without writing it to the windbg console.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I went ahead and tested with the latest WinDbgX, and it appears to have about the same performance as the existing WinDbg release.

Comment: @ThomasWeller closing the output window doesn't appear to be a thing, clicking the "X" causes it to disappear momentarily, but it comes right back.

Comment: @AlexGaynor: I'm sad to hear that the new version does not provide the performance benefits promised. On channel 9 they discussed the neccessity of the old version of synchronizing the output which was removed or at least improved in the new version. :-(

Comment: haven't played around with it, but take a look at .shell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-shell--command-shell-

Answer (score 3):

You want the `.outmask` meta-command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-outmask--control-output-mask-

`.outmask` allows you to control which message types are sent to the output window and log file. The `/l` switch can allow you to change just the types that reach the output window, without affecting which types will reach the log file.

For example, this command will turn off all output to the output window while still sending normal messages to the log file:

```
.outmask- /l 0xffff
```

Although probably `.outmask- /l 1` is all you need, which turns off just normal message output, but errors and warnings will still show up in the output window. Use `.outmask /d` to reset output settings back to the default when you're done.

In combination with the ability of `.printf` to output different message types, you can make it so you still have some idea what's going on, as well. Turn off normal message output to the window with `.outmask- /l 1`. Now you can use `.printf /oe "message"` in a breakpoint command somewhere to write an error message, which will still be sent to the output window so you can tell what's happening at certain points in the process.

Answer (score 2):

you can patch **dbgeng!g_OutputControl** global to disable writing to console and only write to log file

but I don't know if you will have a performance gain or not

looking for a txt file

```
C:\>dir /b *.txt
File Not Found
```

opening a debugging session

```
C:\>cdb calc


Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.400 X86

ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
774005a6 cc              int     3
```

in the opened debugging session
spawn a parent debugger to debug the windbg running your debuggee

```
0:000> .dbgdbg
Debugger spawned, connect with
    "-remote npipe:icfenable,pipe=cdb_pipe,server=xxxx"
```

in the spawned parent patch the global and detach

```
ed dbgeng!g_OutputControl 0
.detach
q
```

open a logfile in your debugging session

```
0:000> .logappend c:\foo.txt
Opened log file 'c:\foo.txt'
```

set a conditional breakpoint and start the session

```
0:000> bp ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection "kb;gc"
0:000> bl
 0 e 773a7790     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection "kb;gc"
0:000> g
```

**there is no console output here**

doing a ctrl+c to stop session and quitting the session

```
eax=7ffde000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=773ff1d3 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77394108 esp=016ef8a8 ebp=016ef8d4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77394108 cc              int     3
0:001> q
quit:
```

check for the log file and confirm if it has voluminous data written to it
RtlEnterCriticalSection Api is a very hot Api

```
C:\>dir /b *.txt
foo.txt

C:\>ls -l foo.txt
-rw-rw-rw-  1  0 **1754920** 2017-09-15 00:27 foo.txt
```

C:>head foo.txt

```
Opened log file 'c:\foo.txt'
0:000> bp ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection "kb;gc"
0:000> bl
 0 e 773a7790     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection "kb;gc"
0:000> g
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
000cf114 77425f4b 000d0138 7724d80b 00000000 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection
000cf158 773ea40a 000d0000 50180162 00000044 ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap+0x9d
000cf23c 773b5ae0 00000044 00000000 00000000 ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeap+0xc4
000cf2c0 77384726 000d0000 40180060 00000044 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x23a
```

there are more tha 22k lines written to this file

```
C:\>wc -l foo.txt
22543 foo.txt
```

C:>tail foo.txt

```
000cf838 773c37be 00462d6c 7ffdb000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
000cf850 00000000 00462d6c 7ffdb000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
(c80.8ec): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=7ffde000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=773ff1d3 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77394108 esp=016ef8a8 ebp=016ef8d4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
77394108 cc              int     3
0:001> q
quit:

C:\>
```